# Setting a Variable in Laravel's Fluent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I need to reorder some data using Laravel and (presumably) fluent. The raw testing & working SQL would look something like this:

```
SET @ordering = 0;

UPDATE data 
SET `order` = (SELECT @ordering := @ordering + 1) 
WHERE category_id = 400 
ORDER BY points;
```

Of course that isn't going to work out of the box, but I have no idea how to get it working. I've tried all sorts of tricks. The most obvious to me would be to just do (also tried as `statement()`):

```
DB::UPDATE(
    'SET @ordering = 0; 
    UPDATE data 
    SET `order` = (@ordering = @ordering + 1) 
    WHERE category_id = ? 
    ORDER BY points', 
    [400]
);
```

But this gets me an error:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE data SET `order` = (@ordering = @ordering + 1) WHERE categ' at line 1 (SQL: SET @ordering = 0; UPDATE data SET `order` = (@ordering = @ordering + 1) WHERE category_id = 400 ORDER BY points)'

I've tried every variation I can think of, but nothing seems to take. How can I set a db variable and use that to update?

Comment: Is this on an existing data set or can you update the schema and make the column auto incrementing? `DB::statement('ALTER Table data add order INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT;');`

Comment: This is a table with many categories, each one is separately ordered and needs to be re-orderable by different criteria.